# Cannot select ViewController as object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to connect a button to the ViewController.m but I cannot select the 'ViewController' option in the 'Object' section as shown in the image. Only the 'Exit' option is available.

I dragged the button from Main.storyboard into the ViewController.m, and the window popped up as shown.

Any advice? Thanks!

The weird thing is, I am able to select ViewController in one of my VieControllerScene, but not in any of the others.
[Able to select ViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdMdY.png)

As for the rest of the buttons that I try to drag it into the code, this pops up:
[Object defaulted at Exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Ygl.png)

Comment: You are using xib or storyboard?

Comment: Where are you dragging the connection when trying to add it?

Comment: I'm dragging the connection from Main.storyboard to ViewController.m

Comment: Does having multiple View Controller scenes affect this? I am able to select the ViewController in only one the scenes but not the rest. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wand to connect your UI objects as IBOutlets in your controller's code, you should be sure that:

1. Your controller class is exclusive, that there are no two ViewController classes in your project;
2. Choose correct object class in IB in your storyboard.

[image: Identity inspector -> Custom class -> Class]

Answer (score -1):

After quite some time, I realised that adding a custom class helped, as probably I am using multiple ViewControllers. It will be great if someone can still explain why the error occured though. :)

[Adding a class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOiWd.png)